# Does usb creator support DVD ISOs?

Tags: dvd, iso, usb-creator

I'm trying to make a bootable flash drive using usb-creator. My iso file is a DVD iso. When I choose the ISO it doesn't appear on the source list. No error, just nothing happens. On the file type option, there's only "Disk Images" and "CD Images" but there's no "DVD Images" so I think DVD iso is not supported.

Is that true?

Answer (score 1):

No, the DVD iso shows up and works just fine.  Of course, your USB stick has to be large enough to handle it.

Comment: The iso file size is 1 GB. The USB stick is 4 GB. Is it because DVDs are 4.7 GB?

Comment: @Ron, it used to require an 8 gb stick to fit, but the new image is only 1 gb so should work on a 4gb stick just fine.